# Draggable large list performance - Vue js

Tags: performance, vuejs3, virtualscroll, vue.draggable

I have a project in vue 3 where i have to show multiple horizontal lists. The items of those lists must be draggable. When some lists are very large (over 2000 items) the performance of the drag event is very slow.

At the moment i am using this component for dragging https://github.com/SortableJS/vue.draggable.next.

I have found that using virtual scrolling may be a good solution for improving the performance, so I found this component https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller.

The problem is that I cannot use them both. Is there any way to use make them work both, or any other solution for improving performance ?